# Get text on individual links using xpath and regex

Tags: python, html, regex, web-scraping, scrapy

I am working on a scrapy project and we are scraping a news website.
There is a div that contains the sites tags and it may have several links.
For example:

```
<div class="article__tags">
<a href="/example/ops.html">
OPS
</a>
<a href="/example/covid-19.html">
Covid-19
</a>
<a href="/example/usa.html">
USA
</a>
</div>
```

and i am trying to get the individual tags.
I am doing it like this:

```
tags = html.xpath(
            '//div[@class="article__tags"]/a/text()').re('(\w+)')
```

And in the above example i get the following tags:
OPS
USA
COVID
19
which is incorrect since covid and 19 are the same tag.
¿How can get the links texts correct?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it by changing it to

```
tags = html.xpath(
        '//div[@class="article__tags"]/a/text()').extract()
```